# Linux API to be used for creating new process in Multicore process

Tags: linux, memory, process, posix, multicore

**BackGround:** Developing a OSEK based RTOS wrapper for a multicore system in linux enviroment by making use of Posix Api's

I understand that there are Linux API's Fork, Exec and System in order to create a child process from the existing process. My aim is to have multiple processes in the system who does not share the same memory as parent process.

The ultimate aim is to have different thread on process where each process is free from interference from others. Now also there are API mmap to bind the memory of a process to specific area.

**Question:** What is the best way for creating multiple process and to make sure that process does not share the same memory ?

**PS:** I am new to linux Os and have read lot of theory till now but I am not sure on the implementation front as to what results I may get. A little help from the experts may make things easy.

Comment: what's OSEK and RTOS ???  Why don't you write also POSIX (all uppercase)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it depends if you want more or less portability.  You can use posix threads that have the possibility to share virtual space between them.  When you use **fork(2)**, you get completely different virtual spaces in each process (with copied on write data, so it's a good and portable solution in terms of efficiency, as normally you do an **exec(2)** afterwards)  Not all environments have posix threads access.

By the way, linux **fork(2)** system call is implemented in terms of **clone(2)** system call.  This last one is a more general mechanism to fork new processes/threads that allow more control on what is shared and what not.  See manpages for **fork(2)**, **vfork(2)** and **clone(2)** system calls/wrappers.

Your question is not very specific in the requirements you have, so there are a lot of possibilities.

Comment: The main use case for me to create multiple process is to map them to different core and control their memory access and thread execution. OSEK (along with AUTOSAR) is a standard specifying requirements for Os used in automotive domain.

Comment: That's already handled in kernel.  User processes/threads distribute almost uniformly in linux kernel.  Some exceptions to this rule are some kind of hardware interrupts that are forced to happen always in the same core, there's a lot of kernel flexibility at this level.